# What is the usage of Local Database Cache project type in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio, project-types

What is the usage of `Local Database Cache` project type in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It creates a SQL Compact database in the client app.

It also sets up all the code, prep work, for both client and server sides, to synchronize the compact database with the server one occasionally, via a WCF service.